# How can we identify the RAID configuration externally?

Tags: raid, troubleshooting

The admin responsible for an old server has left the company and no one knows how to access it. This server is business critical so we can't unplug it to regain access.

How can we tell what RAID configuration has been set up by examining the hardware?

We can afford to purchase any necessary equipment such as an oscilloscope or EMF meter.

Comment: Would you mind adding further details that might help? For example, what operating system do you suspect? What are the hardware details (e.g. model numbers, number of disks) you can determine?

Comment: It looks like there's a RAID card and eight drives.